# server side account check - is user registered (backand.com)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, contacts, user-accounts, backand

i currently stuck on building an account check like whatsapp.
When a user clicks on his smartphone on his/her contacts, it should display, which user has an existing account.

So in theory it should post all user contacts to server, server checks if there is an account with this email adresse and sends the "updated list" back to the client.

Sounds easy, but how do i do something like that :)
Getting the contacts is working, also posting contacts to server.

I had my backend on backand.com and building an app with Ionic/Angular.

Answer (score 1):

This should be very simple.

The core functionality here is based on Backand built in 'users' object, it holds all users you've added to your app, a simple GET to this object will return all your users details including emails.

Now you can add a [serverside js](http://docs.backand.com/en/latest/apidocs/customactions/) action that

1. gets the contacts details from the client-side app in the request body (as JSON)
2. does an [$http call to the users object](http://docs.backand.com/en/latest/getting_started/quick_reference/index.html#manipulating-objects) ro fetch exiting users.
3. loops the contacts and search for them in the users array

Comment: you mean an "action - on demand", right? is there any example or tutorial how to do that? getting contacts as JSON is easy. than i had to post them to server via $http.post, right? but what is the URL where i had to post it? https://api.backand.com/1/objects/users